# Counting unique values in all columns of a csv file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, csv

I have a CSV file, a.csv, which have 15000 rows and 16 columns. 
It have numbers, sentences, dates in different columns.

It looks like this:

```
A, B, C, D
a  b  c  d
e  f  g  h
e  i  j  k
a  m  n  k
```

How can I count the unique values in each column separately and print them at once?

I want an output that looks like this:

```
A 2
B 4
C 4
D 3
```

Any advice or help are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you could transpose the text (rows→columns), then filtering lines would be easier.

Comment: What is the field delimiter? The first row seems to use commas (and a space?) while the others just use two spaces...

Comment: the field delimiter is comma ',' .

Answer (score 2):

using xsv (https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv) starting from

```
A,B,C,D
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
e,i,j,k
a,m,n,k
```

and running

```
xsv stats input.csv --everything | xsv select field,cardinality >output.txt
```

you will have

```
field,cardinality
A,2
B,4
C,4
D,3
```